# D3 line graph not filling entire svg width

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

As the title states, I have created a D3 line/area graph, and I am finding it difficult to get the graph's width to remain constant, depending on the amount of data I have given it to render, it scales the width of the graph accordingly, but I am unsure of how I can get it to remain at a constant width, regardless of the amount of data given, which is what I would like to achieve.

I imagine it has something to do with the scaling of the x and y coordinates, but I am stuck at the moment and can't seem to figure out why it is doing this.

Here is the code I have thus far,

```
  //dimensions and margins
  var width = 625,
  height = 350,
  margin = 5,

  // get the svg and set it's width/height
  svg = d3.select("#main")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  //initialize the graph
  init([
        [12345,42345,32345,22345,72345,62345,32345,92345,52345,22345], 
        [1234,4234,3234,2234,7234,6234,3234,9234,5234,2234] 
      ]);

  $("button").live('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(id == "one"){
        updateGraph([
                [52345,32345,12345,22345,62345,72345,92345,32345,22345,22345,52345,32345,12345,22345,62345,72345,92345,32345,22345,22345,52345,32345,12345,22345,62345,72345,92345,32345,22345,22345], 
                [4234,12345,2234,32345,6234,7234,9234,3234,2234,2234,4234,1234,2234,3234,6234,7234,9234,3234,2234,2234,4234,1234,2234,3234,6234,7234,9234,3234,2234,2234] 
              ]);
      }else if(id == "two"){
        updateGraph([
              [12345,42345,32345,22345,72345,62345,32345,92345,52345,22345,12345,42345,32345,22345,72345,62345,32345,92345,52345,22345,12345,42345,32345,22345,72345], 
              [1234,2345,3234,2234,7234,6234,3234,9234,5234,2234,1234,4234,3234,2234,7234,6234,3234,9234,5234,2234,1234,4234,3234,2234,7234] 
            ]);
      }

  });

function init(data){

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,data[0].length])
    .range([margin, width-margin]),

  y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(data[0])])
    .range([height-margin, margin]),

  /* line path generator */
  line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d); }),

  /* area path generator */
  area = d3.svg.area().interpolate('monotone')
    .x(line.x())
    .y1(line.y())
    .y0(y(0)),

  groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

  svg.select("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data[0])
  .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", line.x())
    .attr("cy", line.y())
    .attr("r", 4);

  /* add the areas */
  groups.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d",area)
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return (i == 0 ? "steelblue" : "red" ); });

  /* add the lines */
  groups.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
}

function updateGraph(data){

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,data[0].length])
    .range([margin, width-margin]),

  y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(data[0])])
    .range([height-margin, margin]),

  /* line path generator */
  line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d); }),

  /* area path generator */
  area = d3.svg.area().interpolate('monotone')
    .x(line.x())
    .y1(line.y())
    .y0(y(0));

  groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data),

  circles = svg.select("g")
    .selectAll("circle");

  circles.data(data[0])
      .exit().remove();

  circles.data(data[0])
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("cx", line.x())
        .attr("cy", line.y())
        .attr("r", 4);

  /* animate circles */
  circles.data(data[0])
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", line.x())
    .attr("cy", line.y());

  /* animate the lines */
  groups.select('.line')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d",line);

  /* animate the areas */
  groups.select('.area')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d",area);

}
```

​

As well as a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JL33M/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The width of the graph depends on the `range()` you give it. `range([0,100])` will always "stretch" the `domain()` values to take up 100 units.

That's what your code is currently doing:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,data[0].length])
  .range([margin, width-margin]);// <-- always a fixed width
```

You want the width to depend on the number of data entries. Say you've decided you want each data point to take up 5 units, then `range()` needs to depend on the size of the dataset:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,data[0].length])
  .range([margin, 5 * data[0].length]);// <-- 5 units per data point
```

Of course, under these conditions, your graph width grows with the dataset; if you give it a really long data array of, say, 500 points, the graph would be 2500 units wide and likely run off screen. But if your data is such that you know the maximum length of it, then you'll be fine.

On an unrelated note, I think your code could use a refactoring to be less repetitive. You should be able to achieve what you're doing with a single `update()` function, without the need for the `init()` function.

[This tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/3808218) by mbostock describe the "general update pattern" I'm referring to. Parts [II](http://bl.ocks.org/3808221) and [III](http://bl.ocks.org/3808234) then go on to explaining how to work transitions into this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! :) One thing that is confusing me a bit though, is that even though I specify a fixed width, the graph never fills up the entire container, I understand that it scales, but should it not scale the graph to the width and height I gave it? In my honest opinion it is very inconsistent and even though it makes sense, it creates a real problem when trying to achieve consistency between data sets. So if I understand you correctly, my code as it is should yield a graph that stretches to fit the entire width I specified it to use?

Comment: Isn't it because you're subtracting the margin?

Comment: If only it would "stretch" the domain values, in some sane way.  There is no pattern to the result at all.  Sometimes larger values get a skinny result, and smaller get a wide result.  Sometimes the opposite is true.  What should happen, is the longest bar is set to the max-width, and all others proportionately scaled.

Comment: would like to know how to make that work @JosephK

Comment: @Hugo Somewhat unclear what you're asking, but if your javascript code "knows" the exact pixel width you want to fill up (either bc it's a hardcoded width, OR bc you measured the container using getBoundingBox() or related methods) then just set the scale's range based on those measurements. On the other hand, if you don't know or don't want to measure the available space, try using percentage-based widths instead. In that case, the scale's range would be [0, 100], so it will yield values from 0 to 100, and then you append '%' to the value (rather than the usual 'px').